# Increase Y axis label length

Tags: javascript, plotly

I need large labels in plotly js heat map. It takes around 9-11 characters. I tried increasing the width of different svg elements it is using.

In below code pen replace the y axis content with
 y: ['Morning My Text', 'Afternoon  My Text', 'Evening  My Text'],

https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/4cff7f15035142f88f62c9a4700c1d70

The result shows "ing My Text" . Morn gets hidden.

```
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
  </script>
</body>


var data = [
  {
    z: [[1, 20, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, -10, 20]],
    x: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    y: ['Morning My Text', 'Afternoon  My Text', 'Evening  My Text'],
    type: 'heatmap'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a second parameter to `Plotly.newPlot` which contains layout information. For example: `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {yaxis: {automargin: true}});` will stretch the plot margins to fit the Y-axis labels.

See https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/ and https://plot.ly/javascript/reference

Answer (score 0):

**You can set the margin length dynamically.**

```
var maxLabelLength = 20;
const letterWidth = 7;
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart',
  margin:{
    l: maxLabelLength * letterWidth
  }
};
```